# Taking string input in C

Tags: c

I want to take input from user (string). however, i want to restrict the user to enter only three types, and then proceed with the program. otherwise i want to print invalid, if any other string has been input. I wrote a program, but it certainly doesnt work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    char hotel[100], first, second, third;

    printf("Enter Your Choice: ");
    scanf("%s", &hotel);

    if (hotel != first && hotel != second && hotel != third) {
        printf("Invalid!");
    } else {
        printf("OK");
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to put newlines in.

Comment: a) `first` etc are the wrong type. b) they are *uninitialised*. c) you must compare strings in C with `strcmp` not `==` or `!=`.

Comment: Please take a look at the compiler's warnings and see what you can do to correct it.

Comment: Never use `scanf()` with plain `%s` (no width specifier).  And don't discard the result.  You should have `if (scanf("%99s", hotel) != 1) { fputs("Input error!", stderr); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }` there.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job (take a look to the comments to get the explanations):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /* to use strcmp */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char hotel[100];

    /* You need to initialize those strings and use the right type (char* or char[]) */
    const char *first = "first";
    const char *second = "second";
    const char *third = "third" ;

    printf("Enter Your Choice: ");
    scanf("%s", hotel); /* format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[100]' [-Wformat] => remove the '&' */
    /* Note: using fgets instead of scanf is safer */

    /* Use strcmp to compare strings */
    if (strcmp(hotel, first) != 0 && strcmp(hotel, second) != 0 && strcmp(hotel, third) != 0) {
        printf("Invalid!");
        return 1; /* Your main function should return an integer value (0 if success) */
    } else {
        printf("OK");
        return 0; /* Your main function should return an integer value (0 if success) */
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to play it safe: `scanf("%s", hotel);` => `if (scanf("%99s", hotel) != 1) { printf("Unexpected end of file\n"); return 1; }`

Comment: @chqrlie or use `fgets` instead like I suggest in comment :)

Comment: `fgets()` however is not a direct replacement for `scanf("%s",...)`: `fgets()` will read a full (but potentially empty) line including he trailing newline if any, whereas `scanf()` will skip initial white space, including newlines and read the first word, leaving any subsequent white separator pending  in the standard input buffer. Very different semantics.